# Is there a way to get all words from the dictionary in the layout "word",

Tags: javascript, layout

So, i am trying to make a word predictor with the whole dictionary words but i want the layout to be like:

```
var wpredict "word1", "word2",
```

can somebody tell me a way to get all words from the dictionary into the layout of that, or send me all the words?

Answer (score 0):

you could go to a site like angelfire.com/extreme4/safer_sephiroth/EVERY_WORD_EVER.htm and copy and paste it into a script as a template string then format it into an array...

```js
const everyword = `aaaarrrrgggghhhh

aaargh

Aachen

Aardman

aardvark

aardvarks

aardwolf

Aarhus

Aaron

Aaronson

abacus

...`.split("\n\n");

console.log(everyword);
```

Its not a very elegant solution, and I don't know how well `.split` works with large strings but it should work.

If that's not good enough here is a hard typed list in array format:
https://codepen.io/TheOnlyRealMe/pen/XWMmvaB?editors=0010

Comment: I’m looking for a layout like *var wpredict “word1”, “word2”,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this method should create an array of every word (`const everyword = ["word1", "word2", "..."]`) is that not what you wanted? If not it should be easy to format it however you want with `.join(",")` or whatever

Comment: `var wpredict “word1”, “word2”, "..."` is not a valid format; do you mean an array, like:`var wpredict = [“word1”, “word2”, "..."]`?

Comment: also I edited my answer with an alternative if you want

Comment: Can someone just send me the layout array of var wpredict "word1", etc

Comment: @DaGamerRaider_YouTube, as I said, the layout you're asking for is not valid in js, yet I gave you the closest solution using various methods. Can you please explain why you wont except the answer I gave you, and how you intend to use this? Also did you check the link to the alternative?

Comment: CAN SPMEONE JUST SEND ME IT IN MY LAYOUT PLEASE

Comment: I am trying to be patient, but how experienced are you in js? Can you please answer my questions? I am trying to help, but your request is confusing, the layout you are requesting is simply an error. If you tell me what you are trying to do with this, or give me more of your code I may be able to understand what you need. Can I chat with you at 5 hours and 15 minutes from now?